# Jquery nao funciona em PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Não sei o motivo. a pagina nao funciona. alguem sabe me ajudar a descobrir o problema?
Quero que a mascara de data funcione nos campos `data` e no campo `Venc_Garantia`

alguem pode me ajudar?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="C:\wamp\www\cadastro\javascript\jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="C:\wamp\www\cadastro\javascript\jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function($){
$("#data").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
$("#venc_garantia").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
});
</script>

<title></title>
</head>
Caso NAO seja DELL clicar aqui: <input name="cadastro_dell" type="button" 
onClick="location.href='http://localhost/cadastro/cadastro.php'" value="Cadastro DELL">
<body>
<form name="signup" method="post" action="cadastrando_dell.php"> <br /><br />
Fabricante: <input type="text" name="fabricante" maxlength="10" /> <br /><br />
Modelo: <input type="text" name="modelo" maxlength="50" /> <br /><br />
Tipo: <input type="text" name="tipo" maxlength="50"/> <br /><br />
Data de Envio(ano-mes-dia): <input type="text" name="data" id="data"/> <br /><br />
URL DELL: <input type="text" name="url" maxlength="100"/> <br /><br />
Numero de serie: <input type="text" name="serie" maxlength="12"/> <br /><br />
Proprietario: <input type="text" name="proprietario" maxlength="30"/> <br /><br />
Origem: <input type="text" name="origem" maxlength="30"/> <br /><br />
Venc. Garantia(ano-mes-dia): <input type="text" name="venc_garantia"          id="venc_garantia"/>
Tipo de Instalacao: <input type="text" name="tipo_instalacao" maxlength="30"/> <br />               
Configuracao: <input type="text" name="configuracao" maxlength="150"/> <br /><br />
uname_a: <input type="text" name="uname_a" maxlength="100"/> <br /><br />
Instalacao: <input type="text" name="instalacao" maxlength="250"/> <br /><br />
Situacao (status): <input type="text" name="status" maxlength="15"/> <br /><br />
Servicos: <input type="text" name="servicos" maxlength="150"/> <br /><br />


Descricao: <input type="text" name="descricao" maxlength="150" /> <br /><br />
Quantidade: <input type="text" name="quantidade" maxlength="5"/> <br /><br />
Numero de Tombamento: <input type="text" name="tombamento" maxlength="13"/> <br /><br />
Local de Uso: <input type="text" name="local" maxlength="20"/> <br /><br />


<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar DELL" name="botao"/>



</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["botao"])){
    if(empty($tipo) || empty($tombamento) || empty($status)){
            echo "Preencha todos os campos!";           
    }
}
?>      

</body>

</html>
```

`

Estou usando o WAMP com tudo atualizado, mas mesmo fazendo referência ao arquivo Jquery eu não vejo aplicado a mascara, o que pode ser?

Comment: Obviamente percebi mal a pergunta

Comment: Se está utilizando um servidor, você não pode apontar o endereço do arquivo através do disco local, deve estar em uma pasta compartilhada pelo apache, como a www e utilizar o caminho relativo, como nas respostas abaixo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso você esteja rodando esta pagina sobre um `SERVIDOR` você deve referenciar o javascript assim

```
<script src="/cadastro/javascript/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/cadastro/javascript/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
```

O erro provavelmente acontece porque esta referencia do arquivo javascript fica inacessível sobre um servidor.

Comment: Poxa cara, nem sei como agradeçer. O pior que olhei N tutoriais na internet e todos me mostravam codigos meia boca e eu fazendo tudo como mandavam e nao rodava. Agora foi certinho! MUITO OBRIGADO MESMO!!!

Answer (score 1):

Troque os caminhos dos arquivos

```
<script src="C:\wamp\www\cadastro\javascript\jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="C:\wamp\www\cadastro\javascript\jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

por:

```
<script src="nome_da_pasta_ou_projeto/javascript/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="nome_da_pasta_ou_projeto/javascript/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, o erro está em como você fez a leitura dos scripts, como sua pagina esta rodando em um servidor WAMP ele não acessa os arquivos normalmente. De uma olhada no console de erros do navegador clicando em inspecionar elemento no Chrome e depois em console, provavelmente deve ter retornado dois erros 404 e erros de função desconhecida já que os scripts não foram carregados.
Outra dica é carregar jquery-1.5.2.min.js direto do CDN do Google, assim:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Poderia funcionar se informar no SRC algo como:

```
<script src="file:///c:/myScript.js">
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Referenciar o arquivo pelo caminho local não é uma boa prática e não vai funcionar em navegadores com segurança habilitada ou quando acessado de outro computador. Esses são alguns dos motivos pelo qual sua resposta recebeu votos negativos. Você pode editar a resposta e melhorá-la ou então removê-la para anular os votos contrários. Sugiro também que leia sobre [como escrever uma boa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) em nossa Central de Ajuda. Abraço!